# Flutter HTTPS web frontend call JSON API with XMLHttpRequest via HTTP (mixed content)

Tags: flutter-web

I created a webpage with flutter and deployed. I open in a browser using https and got a error message:

[image]

Do you have any idea what would be the best approach to solve this issue in general? I mean I have public frontend which communicate with insecure http backend api services. Should I use SSL connection for backend communications? Or should choose different flutter component?
My flutter code:

```
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.0.77:4010/status-board/'));
```

Comment: This is not really Flutter related. Please search for 'mixed content' on SO and you will get lots of explanations and suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Flutter generates the JS code which include XMLHttpRequest call. I am looking for alternatives to replace flutter/dart http.get method or anything what help. You have right anyway this is a general issue, I'd like to get recommendation for architecture as well.

Comment: The safest and more future proof way would be using https in the backend. Tendency is that web agents are restricting access to non-secure resources. Search for 'mixed content' here on SO for explanations and suggestions.

Comment: Peter, thanks again. I was afraid you say this, so I go forward on this way. In this case the next challenge is: to solve self signed certificate in XmlHttpRequest. But it is a different topic.